# Can't reach shared folder from VM over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, network-share, windows-8, vmware-fusion

My network knowledge is a bit lacking so I'm looking for some help on why we can't access a shared folder.  We have a Windows 8 VM on a Mac host that is sharing a folder that we want accessible from several other Windows 8 VMs on Mac hosts (using VMware Fusion).  When those other hosts are on the local network both the host and VM can access the shared network location/folder without issue.

However, we also have a VPN server set up.  When those hosts are not on the network (they are mobile and need to be able to access the network location from home) they can connect to the VPN and reach the shared folder.  However the client VMs cannot access the shared location/file.  They cannot even ping the server where the shared file is located or the VPN server.

I'm sure there is something simple I am missing but I'm not sure what it is, any help/suggestions?

Comment: If you VPN in from a VM instead of a host can the VM then see the share?

Comment: I'm not able to ping the VPN server from the VM so I didn't expect to be able to connect to the VPN.

Comment: Then the VMs probably aren't in bridged mode: http://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-E498672E-19DD-40DF-92D3-FC0078947958.html - try that...